# Error 429 [type=reduce_search_phase_exception]

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have many languages for my docs and am following this pattern: [One index per language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/one-lang-docs.html). In that they suggest to search across all indices with the

```
/blogs-*/post/_count
```

pattern. For my case I am getting a count across the indices of how many docs I have. I am running my code concurrently so making many requests at same time. If I search

```
/blogs-en/post/_count
```

or any other language then all is fine. However if I search

```
/blogs-*/post/_count
```

I soon encounter:

```
"Error 429 (Too Many Requests): [reduce]  [type=reduce_search_phase_exception]
"
```

Is there a workaround for this? The same number of requests is made regardless of if I use

```
/blogs-en/post/_count or /blogs-*/post/_count.
```

I have always used the same number of workers in my code but re-arranging the indices to have one index per language suddenly broke my code.

EDIT: It is a brand new index without any documents when I start the program and when I get the error I have about 5,000 documents so not under any heavy load.

Edit: I am using the mapping found in the above-referenced link and running on a local machine with all the defaults of ES...in my case shards=5 and replicas=1. I am really just following the example from the link.

EDIT: The errors are seen with as few as 13-20 requests are made and I know ES can handle more than that. Searching /blogs-en/post/_count instead of /blogs-*/post/_count, etc.. can easily handle thousands with no errors.

Another Edit: I have removed all concurrency but still can only access 40-50 requests before I get the error.

Comment: When hitting an HTTP 429, it means that your server is not able to keep up with the queries you're sending to it. What are the specs of your server (CPU, RAM, network)? Can you share the results you get from `curl localhost:9200/_cat/thread_pool?v` and `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_nodes/stats` ?

Comment: Additionally from what @Val asked I would be interested in seeing the full error message, to see which queue is getting full. Also, how many indices you have now? It's  big move from (maybe one index with multi-language inside) to multi-indices (one language per index). While in the first case there was only one request going to one index, now you have a request for each index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get an error for that request and it returns total documents.
Is you'r cluster under load?
Anyway, using simple aggregation you can get **total document count**  in `hits.total` and **per index document count** in `count_per_index` part of result:

```
GET /blogs-*/post/_search
{
    "size": 0, 
   "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "aggs": {
      "count_per_index": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "_index"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It is a brand new index without any documents yet and when I get the error I have about 5,000 documents so not under any heavy load.

Comment: oops! can you provide you'r mapping and cluster architecture? how many shards and replicas do you use?  I want to reproduce you'r result. Also It's very helpful to remove today's log file and run the commands again to have pure log for these commands.

Comment: I am using the mapping found in the above-referenced link and running on a local machine with all the defaults of ES...in my case shards=5 and replicas=1. The mapping is from the link:
: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/one-lang-docs.html

Comment: I would think that _count would already be highly optimized vs this. If _count isn't already the best it can be then you should file a bug with ES.

Comment: Yes `_count' is optimized. I tried the index and mappings in the above link and it worked correctly. May be the log file can help you

Comment: Thanks for your help! I wasn't able to resolve this but I'll keep trying to debug. Since the bounty will be over I will mark it as accepted and give you the bounty.

Comment: Thanks for that. Actualy these days I didnt have enogh time to reproduce the error.